# Making an INSERT INTO as error/duplicate proof as possible without ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that inserts from `tableA` to `tableB`. Each time the procedure is executed (because tableA will get updated constantly so when the procedure is run it will add missing data into B), it will insert the entire contents of `A` into `B` no matter what.

So in the insert I added a `WHERE` statement to filter "older data" based on the timestamp of when the record was added (insert new records where the timestamp from `tableA` is greater than the one on `tableB` is). The table has no unique identifiers so I'm kinda stuck making the filter as safe as it can, basically the only thing I could consider is the timestamp. I've tried some ways around it but all of them have their cons (commented in each code block).

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB (VALUES)
    SELECT A.VALUES
    FROM A 
    WHERE (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEB) < (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEA)

--THIS DOESN'T EVEN WORK
INSERT INTO TABLEB (VALUES)
    SELECT A.VALUES
    FROM A 
    WHERE A.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEB) AND (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEA)

--IF RUN TWICE IT WILL RUN ON RECORDS CONTAINING TIMESTAMPS WITH THOSE VALUES
INSERT INTO TABLEB (VALUES)
    SELECT A.VALUES
    FROM A 
    WHERE A.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEB) AND (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEA)
      AND A.TIMESTAMP <> (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEA)

--THIS WILL EFFECTIVELY SKIP RECORDS WITH THE TIMESTAMP FROM TABLEA BUT RUN TWICE WILL DUPLICATES THE ONES WITH TIMESTAMP FROM B

INSERT INTO TABLEB (VALUES)
    SELECT A.VALUES
    FROM A 
    WHERE A.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEB) AND (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEA)
      AND A.TIMESTAMP <> (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEA)
      AND A.TIMESTAMP <> (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEB)

--THIS WILL SKIP DATA WITH THE TIMESTAMP FROM B
```

Any help on the logic to make in run ONCE and skip duplicated rows is appreciated.

Comment: why dont add an id column?

Comment: Have you considered using replication?

Comment: You need to have version column in table A with the type of timestamp and a corresponding column in table B with the type of varbinary(8). Is that what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your problem, but this should work. You check what was the last one inserted in Table B and then got all the new records.

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB (VALUES)
    SELECT A.VALUES
    FROM A 
    WHERE TIMESTAMP > (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM TABLEB)
```

Comment: This worked, though I had to select MAX to get to my results, thanks.

Comment: What you mean select MAX ?

Comment: I did something similar but calling timestamp twice for each table, wich worked for other criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting all the records on each insert of table A is pretty much costly. You can use "Scope_Identity" command if you are using T-SQL (sql server). You need to add each record in both tables in same call. Add values to table A then add to table B.

**Here is an example:**

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA (column-names) 
VALUES (values)

DECLARE @LAST_RECORD_ID INT=0

SELECT @LAST_RECORD_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO TABLEB (column-names) 

SELECT 
    (column-names)
FROM TABLEA WHERE TABLEA.ID = @LAST_RECORD_ID
```

Comment: OP table doesnt have ID column

Comment: Table A must have a primary key. If it is true then record in table B should be inserted in same call as in table A.

Comment: at contraty. OP already said `The table has no unique identifiers so I'm stuck`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a version column in table A with the type of timestamp and a corresponding column in table B with the type of varbinary(8).  With this assumption, the following code must work:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB (VALUES)
    SELECT A.VALUES
    FROM A 
    WHERE A.Version > (SELECT MAX(Version) FROM TABLEB)
```

Comment: Why you assume he has that column? and why have different type between both tables?

Comment: Table A needs a timestamp column so that with each new insert into table A a timestamp is generated and stored for the inserted record. And when batch inserting from table A to table B the timestamps also need to be inserted. The varbinary(8) is because in table B no timestamp is generated and the exact timestamps from table A are inserted.

Comment: Already tried using operators, sql doesn't seem to process that as criteria. (0 rows will be affected)

Comment: I have done this scenario for table synchronization and it's working without any problem. Or maybe I didn't understand your question well.